# How to get the MIN and MAX from a dataframe SUBSET which consists of factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, r-markdown, subset

I scraped a table and need to retrieve the Minimum and the Maximum from a subset column in the dataframe.

The table looks like this:

```
      Date          Year Title         Budget        Gross
2     Jun 22        2018 Project 5     $170,000,000  $1,308,334,005
3     Jun 12        2015 Project 4     $215,000,000  $1,669,943,967
4     Jul 18        2001 Project 3     $93,000,000     $365,900,000
5     May 22        1997 Project 2     $75,000,000     $618,638,999
6     Jun 11        1993 Project 1     $63,000,000   $1,045,573,035
```

I need to find the minimum and maximum in column Gross.
This doesn't currently work as the column are vectors. But when I use gsub to replace the comma, it gets messed up.

I don't understand
(1) how to change the vectors to real figures
(2) find the MIN and MAX in this subset

(if this way of thought is correct?)

Thanks for any leads

Comment: You may need `df1$Gross <- as.numeric(gsub("[$,]+", "", df1$Gross))` and then get the `min(df1$Gross)` and `max(df1$Gross)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tidyverse solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(Gross, parse_number)) %>%
  summarise(across(Gross, list(min = min, max = max)))

  Gross_min  Gross_max
1 365900000 1669943967
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to remove both the `,` and the `$` and `$` is a metacharacter in regex to denote the end of the string.  Either we can escape it for place them in a square bracket (`[$,]+` - one or more characters that are either a `$` or `,`) and replace with blank (`""`).  Then, we convert the column to `numeric` (`as.numeric`)

```
df1$Gross <- as.numeric(gsub("[$,]+", "", df1$Gross))
```

Now, we can get the `min` and `max`

```
min(df1$Gross, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 365900000
max(df1$Gross, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1669943967
```

Or use the `range` function

```
range(df1$Gross, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]  365900000 1669943967
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("Jun 22", "Jun 12", "Jul 18", "May 22", 
"Jun 11"), Year = c(2018L, 2015L, 2001L, 1997L, 1993L), Title = c("Project 5", 
"Project 4", "Project 3", "Project 2", "Project 1"), Budget = c("$170,000,000", 
"$215,000,000", "$93,000,000", "$75,000,000", "$63,000,000"), 
    Gross = c("$1,308,334,005", "$1,669,943,967", "$365,900,000", 
    "$618,638,999", "$1,045,573,035")), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```